# How to intercept cross-extension messaging using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, message-passing

I am using selenium webdriver to automate chrome extension testing. I try to use `driver.execute_cdp_cmd(cmd, cmd_args)` to intercept the cross-extension messaging via message passing API. However, I have no idea which method in Chrome DevTools can be used to do so. Any hints are welcome!

Extension A

```
let extPort = chrome.runtime.connect(ExtB);
extPort.postMessage({from: "ExtA", fn: "greeting"});
extPort.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if ((message.from == "ExtB") && (message.fn == "greeting")) {
        console.log("Ext B is enabled");
    }
});
```

Extension B

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
        if ((message.from == "ExtA") && (message.fn == "greeting")) {
                port.postMessage({from: "ExtB", fn: "greeting"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) doesn't have any extension-specific methods so you'll have to inject JS code into the extension context and add a listener inside.

Comment: I can only inject script in a page by CDP. No idea how to inject into an extension for the case that messaging is inside a background script. Or.. should I inject the listener before adding extension to selenium webdriver?

Comment: CDP should be able to inject anywhere, assuming you specify the correct target, check the output of [Target.getTargets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target#method-getTargets).

Comment: Which method do you use to inject script? I inject the script using `page.reload` after getting _generated_background_page.html. I think my method is not correct.

Comment: I don't know Selenium, I know the underlying CDP where injection is performed via Runtime.callFunctionOn or Runtime.evaluate. Look for an analog in Selenium. There may be also a way to call the CDP command directly.